# I am unable to load the properties from properties.conf in scala

Tags: scala, typesafe

I am using the below code to load the properties defined in the application. conf for all three different environments like a stage, dev, prod.

Object ConfigLoader.scala

```
  object ConfigLoader extends Serializable with Loggable {
    
      private var profile = "generic"
    
      def setup(profile1: String): Unit = {
        if (profile1 != null && profile1.nonEmpty) {
          this.profile = profile1
        }
      }
    
      def getProfile(): String = {
        profile
      }
    
      lazy val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    
     lazy val ENVIRONMENT = conf.getString("environment.env")

  //collection urls filename
  lazy val COLLECTION_URLS_FILENAME = conf.getString("collection.filename")

  //schema filename
  lazy val post_asset_actuals_schema_filename = conf.getString("schema.post_asset_actuals_schema_filename")
  lazy val put_asset_collection_schema_filename = conf.getString("schema.put_asset_collection_schema_filename")
```

Application.conf contains the below details.

```
environment {
  env = "DEV"
}

collection {
  filename = "collection_url.properties"
}

schema {
  post_asset_actuals_schema_filename = "post_asset_actuals_schema.json"
  put_asset_collection_schema_filename = "put_asset_collection_schema.json"
  put_asset_rule_schema_filename = "put_asset_rule_schema.json"
  put_asset_rule_subscribe_schema_filename = "put_asset_rule_subscribe_schema.json"
}
```

[image: Click the image]

```
    Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'collection'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
at com.x.y.draxcore.util.ConfigLoader$.COLLECTION_URLS_FILENAME$lzycompute(ConfigLoader.scala:55)
at com.x.y.draxcore.util.ConfigLoader$.COLLECTION_URLS_FILENAME(ConfigLoader.scala:55)
at com.x.y.draxws.service.route.AssetFilterRoute$.<init>(AssetFilterRoute.scala:42)
at com.x.y.draxws.service.route.AssetFilterRoute$.<clinit>(AssetFilterRoute.scala)
```

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigFactory.load()` loads the config from `application.conf` from root. In your case, you need to load e.g. dev like this: `ConfigFactory.load("dev/application.conf")`